# What is the problem in this op-amp oscillator that oscilloscope does not show any oscillations?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, proteus

Circuit in Proteus (DC = 1 V):

[image]

Oscilloscope result:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no feedback in your circuit. The op-amp output is only connected to the oscilloscope (note the missing dot).

Answer (score 0):

1. Is op amp powered from differential power supply? With single ended supply circuit won't oscillate, because for 0 at the output, voltage at negative terminal can't fall below 0.
2. Time constant is equal to 4ns, that would result in pretty high oscillation frequency, probably exceeding op amp bandwidth. Maximum output current and resistance would also be limiting factor.
3. As previously was said - there is no feedback connection.

Answer (score 0):

Those resistor values are not realistic for a real world oscillator.

The resistors should be in the range 1kohm to 100kohm. The capacitor value depends upon the frequency you want. A few nanofarad would oscillate in the kHz region. Microfarad values would give you a few Hz or lower.