# If there is no feedback connection in this circuit how can I add a feedback connection?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, oscillator, oscilloscope

[image]

I found a picture from Wikipedia about op-amp oscillator and I designed my circuit with this image from Wikipedia:

[image]

But people say there is no feedback connection in my circuit. (I asked why oscilloscope doesn't show oscillation in my circuit?). Is there a difference between these two circuits?

Comment: Your 1 Ohm resistor might as well just be a wire compared to your 100 Ohm resistor. The values of the R and C matter.

Comment: The second drawing is bad or misleading.  The intention is that the wire crossing the line to Vout is connected to that line, so that there is feedback from Vout to the inputs of the op-amp.  Common practice is to put a dot where wires connect.  If you don't put a dot on a connection, the vertical line should be broken, and staggered to make two "T" connections rather than a cross - that would make it clear that the vertical lines do connect to the Vout line.

Comment: Totally related to this earlier question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609147/what-is-the-problem-in-this-op-amp-oscillator-that-oscilloscope-does-not-show-an

Comment: [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/609161/73158) already told you that the resistor values won't work. The op-amp can't drive such a low resistance load. Why are you still using them?

Comment: VOUT **MUST** CONNECT TO R & R2

Answer (score 1):

"Feedback" means that the op-amp's output voltage is "fed back" to its input, typically through some circuitry, depending on the specific application. There are cases where feedback is not required, but in most time dynamic applications, the op-amp needs feedback to do its magic.

[In your original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609147/what-is-the-problem-in-this-op-amp-oscillator-that-oscilloscope-does-not-show-an), the output was not connected to anything. There is the convention to mark nodes (where two wires connect) with a dot, like in your circuit diagram. This way it is clear which wires are connected and which do just overlap without electrical connection. The schematic you're refering to does not comply with this convention. It's a poor diagram and a good example why those "node dots" are really necessary.